# How can we add featured and unfeatured options for component in the admin backend

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla1.6

How can we add `featured` and `unfeatured` options for component in the admin backend.

I tried using the article manager `(com_content)`. There we can select number of article and changes as featured. But there is no option for unfeatured in `toolbar`.

I have to add the featured options like `publish/unpublish` toolbar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look in the view.html.php for the article list, you will see it's a custom button `JToolBarHelper::custom()`. Providing those options and changing the state of it will be a lot of code and I doubt very much you will be provided with it, therefore I recommend you go to administrator/components/com_content and look through the php files there.

Comment: Thank's for your reply.I have already check with that files. There we can assign only the bulk of article to the `featured` list using the `JToolBarHelper::custom('articles.featured', 'featured.png', 'featured_f2.png', 'JFEATURED', true);` . But we can't assign `unfeatured` for the bulk of articles.

Comment: when you go into the "featured" tab in the article manager, so that only the featured articles are shown, there is a button called "remove", so ther code assigned to this button is what you need ;)

Comment: thanks Lodder. you are right, i got the result :)

Comment: Nice one. Glad you solved it. You should answer the question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the result. This is the following code to done the result.

In `view.html.php` add the follwing line for the unfeature toolbar.

`JToolBarHelper::custom('featured.delete', 'remove.png', 'remove_f2.png', 'JTOOLBAR_REMOVE', true);`

In `featured` controller, there is a function`(delete)` to remove the featured one to unfeatured.